# How to make a dictionary read only via property?

Tags: c#, collections, scope

Hi i have a simple bit of code where i have a private field of a dictionary, and a property that exposes it via get.

But i can still insert to this dictionary from other classes, and was wondering how i can prevent that so i can only insert to the dictionary via the field within the class it is defined and not via the property that exposes it?

This is my field/property code:

```
    private Dictionary<UnitType, Entity> _systems;
    public Dictionary<UnitType, Entity> Systems => _systems;
```

In some other class i am still able to do `MyClass.Systems.Add()` which i want to prevent.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Keep your Dictionary in a private property or field. Use a second (public) property to expose the dictionary wrapped in a [ReadOnlyDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @elgonzo so my read only dictionary casts the dictionary every time i call it right?

Comment: No. I said "...dictionary **wrapped** in a ReadOnlyDictionary". Look up the documentation for ReadOnlyDictionary (i linked in my first comment). Just casting the dictionary to `IReadOnlyDictionary` would still allow it to be cast as normal writable `Dictionary<TKay,TValue>` again...

Comment: However, if you just want Intellisense stop bugging you with also suggesting modifying methods, then of course you can forego using ReadOnlyDictionary wrapper and just cast your dictionary as `IReadOnlyDictionary`.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help, yeah just cleaning up the intellisense is sufficient for this project :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
private Dictionary<UnitType, Entity> _systems;
public IReadOnlyDictionary<UnitType, Entity> Systems => _systems;
```

This would expose only readonly capabilities of the _systems dictionary in the public property.

Comment: Thank you, this does the job for what i need :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Note they can still cast it back to dictionary and modify it, so it only prevents accidental writes